# How many irreductible polynoms of degree $n=3$ are there over $\mathbb Z_{3}=\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many irreductible polynoms of degree $n=3$ are there over $\mathbb Z_{3}=\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}\}$?

Please, check my solution:

$f(x)$ is a polynom of degree $n=3 (\delta f=3) \Rightarrow f(x)=a_0 + a_1 x +a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$. We have three choices for each coeficient, so we can build $3^4 = 81$ polynoms over $\mathbb Z_{3}$. The reductible polynoms are in the shape $p(x)=(x- \alpha)(b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2)$, so we can build $3.(2^3)=24$ reductible polynoms over $\mathbb Z_{3}$. Conclusion: there are 57 irreductible polynoms.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the degree of $f$ if $a_3 = 0$?

Comment: Note that if $p(x)$ is irreducible so is $2p(x)$ (and $4p(x)\equiv p(x)$) so you should be expecting to find an even number.

Comment: Do you count $x(x^2+1)$ as reducible? - you seem to be counting as if $b_i\neq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean degree 3, not degree at most 3. We can assume they are monic. If you want the non-monic ones just multiply all these by 2. So I get these irreducible monic polynomials of degree 3 over $F_3$:

$x^3+2x+1$

$x^3+2x+2$

$x^3+x^2+2$

$x^3+x^2+x+2$

$x^3+x^2+2x+1$

$x^3+2x^2+1$

$x^3+2x^2+x+1$

$x^3+2x^2+2x+2$

Being lazy, I just asked Mathematica to print them out, but I seem to have less than you, so maybe I asked in a silly way.

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: In what way does it not?

Comment: No. He asked us to check his solution. The comments have already pointed out that (indirectly) that it is totally wrong. Now you have two solutions showing that the correct number is 8/16 depending on whether you count $x^3+2x+2$ and $2x^3+x+1$ as the same.

Answer (score 1):

First I count the number of irreducible monic degree-2 polynomials over $\def\zt{\Bbb Z_3}\zt$.  It suffices to count the monic polynomials and then multiply by 2.  A reducible monic polynomial of degree 2 has the form $(x-a)(x-b)$ for $\{a,b\}\subset\{\bar0,\bar1,\bar2\}$. There are 6 possible choices for $\{a,b\}$. There are 9 monic polynomials ($x^2+px+q$ for $\langle p,q\rangle\in\{\bar0,\bar1,\bar2\}^2$), so 3 are irreducible.

Now I count the number of irreducible degree-3 polynomials over $\zt$.  There are $27$ monic polynomials.  A reducible monic polynomial factors as either $(x-a)P_2(x)$ where $P_2$ is irreducible or as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$.  There are $9$ of the former ($3$ choices of $a$ times 3 choices of $P_2$) and $10$ of the latter, totaling $19$.  This leaves $27-19=8$ monic irreducible polynomials, so $16$ irreducible polynomials in all.