# Why isn't every reducible cubic polynomial over $F_q[x]$ of the form $(x^2 + ax + b)(x - c)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

In trying to determine the number of monic irreducible cubic polynomials over $F_q[x]$, where $q$ is prime, I thought that since every reducible cubic must contain a linear factor, each reducible cubic should be able to take the form $$(x+a)(x^2+bx+c)$$
And since there are $q^2$ quadratics over $F_q[x]$, and $q$ linear factors, there must be $q^3$ reducible cubics, but this is obviously a problem because there are then no irreducible cubics!

I've seen ways of determining the number of irreducible cubics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301852/determine-the-number-of-irreducible-monic-polynomials-of-degree-3-in-mathbb-f?newreg=a5d652f39ea54bc49e5dcf5d2a56b39c). Why doesn't my reasoning work? What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some reducible cubics look like
$$(x+r)(x+s)(x+t)$$
and when $r$, $s$ and $t$ are distinct, your method counts them three times.