# Counting reducible monic polynomials in $F_p[x]$

Tags: ring-theory

this question is related to the ones [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301852/determine-the-number-of-irreducible-monic-polynomials-of-degree-3-in-mathbb-f) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40811/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-prime-degree-p-over-finite-fields). I am working on the same problem ("how many monic reducible quadratic polynomials are there in $F_p[x]$"), and I'm unsure about the counting argument: there are $p$ polynomials of the form $(x-a)^2$ - ok - but why are there $\frac{p(p-1)}{2}$ of the form $(x-a)(x-b)$? How does this deal with $ab \equiv bc \mod p$ for different $a,b$? Thanks.

Comment: There are $\binom{p}{2}$ ways to choose two distinct elements out of a set $\Bbb F_p$ of $p$ elements. Are you familiar with binomial coefficients, also called combinations?

Comment: @runway44 Yes. My question was with respect to showing that $(x-a)(x-b)$ give distinct quadratics after reduction modulo $p$.

Comment: They give distinct quadratics because they have different sets $\{a,b\}$ of zeros.